# Difference in pronunciation "Seiten" vs "Saiten"

Tags: pronunciation

I have found in one learning lesson that there is a difference between two words mentioned in title. But I can not find any audio evidence of this. Is there a real difference or it can be neglected in everyday use?

Comment: You can listen to some samples on pons.eu, dict.leo.org and Duden.de.

Answer (score 15):

Both words are pronounced the same (in standard German): [ˈzaɪ̯tn̩], singular [ˈzaɪ̯tə]; source: *Duden-Aussprachewörterbuch* (3rd ed., 1990).

German orthography has a tendency to separate homophones wherever possible; similar cases are *Leib/Laib*, *Lärche/Lerche*.

Comment: Or *dass/das* or *seit/seid* to give some more common examples.

Comment: As long as we're listing them...*Gäste* and *Geste* are relatively common words that sound similar.

Comment: @Dustin Gäste is not homophonous with Geste where I live, it's [ˈɡɛstə] and [ˈɡeːstə] respectively.

Comment: I do not pronounce them the same, I distinguish betwenn Saite with [aɪ̯] and Seite with [ɛɪ̯], as in the answer by @Takkat. But that may be due to the fact that my father is originally from Stuttgart...

Comment: @AlexanderKosubek If we're talking about dialects I do pronounce Seite as ~['zik] (spelled Sigg). Admittedly, I don't know how to pronounce Saite in my dialect as I've never used or encountered it. Anyway, as OP is not asking for a particular dialect it's not helpful to tell any possible pronunciation. There may be hundreds. Hence, chirlu's answer is complete and sufficient.

Comment: @Em1 I was until today not aware that my pronunciation might be not the standard way, I was absolutely sure that there was a difference and anyone who slurred this was just a sloppy speaker. And as chirlu didn't cite any references, I just took the liberty of adding my opinion. I do distinguish between Lärche and Lerche, too, by the way... ;)

Comment: @Alexander Kosubek: Distinguishing between open and closed **short** _e/ä_ vowels, as in _Lärche_ vs. _Lerche_, is a feature of certain dialacts (including Swabian) as well. Standard German only does this for long _e/ä_, the northern regional variant nowhere: _Käse_ [ˈkeːze], _Säge_ [ˈzeːgə]. – _Geste_ is different altogether, there are two pronunciation variants in standard German.

Comment: In the [official spelling rules](http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de/download/regeln2006.pdf) (page 9), both, *Seite/Saite* and *Lärche/Lerche* are used as examples for words that are pronounced identically, but spelt differently.

Comment: @AlexanderKosubek Indeed, I didn't say they were homophonous, but when I heard them in a song, I have to say I couldn't tell the difference without the rest of the sentence to provide context.

Answer (score 7):

Pronunciation is regionally different in Germany. In Swabia this example is pronounced like follows:

> **Saite** [aɪ̯] or [ɔɪ̯] *as in* "**Saite**würstle"
>   **Seite** [ɛɪ̯] *as in* "Gang uff'd **Seite**, I mecht vorbei", *or* ["Seitenbacher"](http://youtu.be/76QHEUEOw_k)

Note however that this is inconsistent. Depending on the word, the Swabian pronunciation of *"ei"* may be [aɪ̯], [ɔɪ̯] or [ɛɪ̯].

The [standard "hochdeutsche](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/7614/23)" pronunciation of *[Seite](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Seite)* (like *[Saite](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Saite)*) is considered as stilted in Swabia. Swabians therefore pronounce these words consistenly with their dialectal tone even when they do not speak dialect otherwise.

This may lead to confusion on how to appropriately pronounce when listening to natives having different regional roots.

Comment: Same for (Upper) Bavarian: Saite ['swatn], Seite ['saɪ̯tn] ... oh, and there's also ['seɪ̯tn] - for "selten", i.e. "rare".